# How to refuse to respond using Flask?

Tags: python, web-services, flask

I'm using Flask to implement a web service.

```py
@app.route('/myservice',methods=['POST'])
def myservice():
    if abnormal_activity_detected():
       refuse to make any response.
```

I'd like to know how to properly refuse to make a response from the server side.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `flask.abort(400)` or any other suitable [HTTP response code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes). Giving absolutely no response is not a part of HTTP.

Comment: @KlausD. Thank you! This could be a very practical way! May I ask if it is possible to refuse to send any http packet back, in order to reduce traffic occupation by such abnormal request source?

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this is to simply close the connection without sending any response. This can be done by manipulating the underlying socket directly.

```
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/myservice', methods=['POST'])
def myservice():
    if abnormal_activity_detected():
        # Get the underlying WSGI environment
        environ = request.environ
        # Access the underlying socket
        socket = environ.get('werkzeug.server.shutdown_socket')
        if socket:
            # Close the connection without sending any response
            socket.close()
            return ''
        else:
            # Fallback to aborting the request if the socket is not available
            abort(403)
    else:
        # Your normal processing code here
        return "Your response here"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Output:

```
 * Serving Flask app 'main'
 * Debug mode: on
WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000
Press CTRL+C to quit
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 420-940-029
```

Comment: This is going to work on the development server only. It will not work in a production setup.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed anwser! Learned alot from such direct and clear way of socket manipulation! Sadly I'm using waitress as the WSGI server. So perhapse I may have to try something more..